# How to test IO with rspec for HighLine gem?

Tags: ruby, highline

I have a class:

```
class Asker

  def initialize
    @cli = HighLine.new
  end 

  def exit_or_continue
    answer = @cli.ask "Type 'quit' to exit at any time, Press 'Enter' to continue"
    exit(0) if answer == 'quit'
  end
end
```

How could I test the `exit_or_continue` method?

Comment: What does `@cli.ask` do? Is it waiting for user input?

Comment: @zeitnot it prints the question and waits for user input

Comment: So you want to test the input right?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you want to test `exit_or_continue` method depending on user input. In this method, there are two main important things. One of them is the user input that `@cli.ask` does and other one is `exit` method that quits the program if the user input is `quit`.

To test these flow we need to stub both `Kernel.exit` and `HighLine#ask` method. 
Firstly, we override the `Kernel.exit` method inside the instance of `Asker` class. The `Kernel` module is included in the `Object` class and every class extend `Object` class implicitly in ruby. So our `Asker` class has the methods of `Kernel` by default.

Why we stub the `exit` method inside the instance of `Asker` class is this would lead to unexpected problems if we stub it globally(In Kernel). What is more, unless we stub this method rspec quits and the rest of tests are not run.

Secondly, we need to stub `HighLine#ask` method which waits for input from the client. `HighLine#ask` is method and this uses `Kernel.gets` under the hood. By stubbing this method, basically we say '*please return this value and do not wait for user input.*'. In other words, with `@cli.stub(ask: 'quit')` this will return `quit` or whatever you want without prompt something.

So I think the following test will accomplish your need. If you encounter any problem please do not hesitate to drop a comment.

```rb
RSpec.describe Asker do

  describe '#exit_or_continue' do
    before do
      @asker = Asker.new
      @cli = @asker.instance_variable_get('@cli')
      @asker.stub(exit: true) # We override Kernel.exit method inside asker instance
    end

    context 'when user input is quit' do
      it 'returns true' do
        @cli.stub(ask: 'quit') # We stub HighLine#ask method to return quit on behalf of the user.
        expect(@sker.exit_or_continue).to be(true)
      end
    end
    context 'when user is input is NOT quit' do
      it 'returns nil' do
        @cli.stub(ask: 'invalid response') # We stub HighLine#ask method to return invalid response on behalf of the user.
        expect(@sker.exit_or_continue).to be_nil
      end
    end
  end
end
```